# Program giving wrong answer when written but gives right answer when copied

Tags: c

I was doing selection sort. The program that I wrote was generating wrong result but when I copied it from a site. The codes are exactly the same except the one copied from the website has more number of spaces. I am providing both the codes. Please help
The code written by me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int position, array[100], n, c, d, swap;
printf ("Enter the number of elements:\n");
scanf ("%d", &n);
printf ("Enter the %d integer\n",n);
for (c=0 ; c < n ; c++)
scanf ("%d", &array[c]);
for (c = 0 ; c < (n-1); c++)
{
position=c;
for (d = c+1; d < n; d++)
{
if (array[position] > array[d]);
position = d;
}
if (position !=c);
{
swap = array[c];
array[c] = array[position];
array[position] = swap;
}
}
printf ("Sorted list in the ascending order:\n");
for (c=0 ; c < n ; c++)
printf ("%d\n", array[c]);
getch();
}
```

The code given in the website

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
   int array[100], n, c, d, position, swap;

   printf("Enter number of elements\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      scanf("%d", &array[c]);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++ )
   {
      position = c;

      for ( d = c + 1 ; d < n ; d++ )
      {
         if ( array[position] > array[d] )
            position = d;
      }
      if ( position != c )
      {
         swap = array[c];
         array[c] = array[position];
         array[position] = swap;
      }
   }

   printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      printf("%d\n", array[c]);

  getch();
}
```

Comment: If you used a pretty print program like AStyle, you would have noticed, by the indentation, what line was wrong.

Comment: This just reeks of copying a homework assignment. LOL.

Comment: As the answer of Paul R suggest, you'd just have to have your code indented properly and you'd see where the problem is. Voting to close.

Answer (score 10):

They are not the same - in one you have:

```
if (array[position] > array[d]);
position = d;
```

whereas in the other you have:

```
     if ( array[position] > array[d] )
        position = d;
```

Notice the stray semicolon in the first one which completely changes the semantics of the program.

Note that you should **always** enable warnings when you compile (e.g. `gcc -Wall`) - this helps to catch silly but hard-so-spot mistakes such as the above example.

---

**EDIT** As noted by @Lucas, you seem to have made the same mistake in other places in the program, e.g. `if (position !=c);` - note that a semicolon in C is not just there for cosmetic effect - a stray semicolon (or missing semicolon) can dramatically change the behaviour of a program.

Comment: same goes for `if (position !=c);`

Comment: thanks a lot!!! i was continuously overlooking this!!!! i made a mess!!!